# My process is already daemonized before calling fork

Tags: upstart

I am starting process with upstart, to run as service using following command but looks like before i call the fork in main() of testservice it's already running as daemon. Any ideas what could be wrong? I use the following command in upstart config file

exec start-stop-daemon -S -x testservice

Br
-S

Answer (score 0):

If you are not changing users, there is no reason to use start-stop-daemon in an upstart script. Simply `exec testservice`.